# Get midi info from keyboard in android level 19

Tags: java, android, midi

I want to write a program in android that when device connect to the piano keyboard via USB and play a note key, my app get witch note is playing. It can use by MidiManager but it request API 23 and I use API level 19. is there any way to get midi device in API 19?